# How to install dotnetnuke in local system?

Tags: dotnetnuke

Can anyone please guide me how to install dnn in local system. How to setup code files and database? I have windows vista os and sql server Express database installed in my system

Thanks,
Merry

Comment: You're missing a webserver (IIS), which comes with Vista Pro/Ultimate, but is not available in Home versiosn. If you have pro, you can go to control panel->add/remove programs->add windows components. If you're using Home, I'd suggest trying out the new http://www.asp.net/webmatrix. 

When installed, you can add your DNN directory as a website. I believe it has a web-based install assistant for setting up your database. (read the instructions that come with it).

Comment: Where can i found "web-based install assistant for setting up your database"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a link that will walk you through the process.

http://www.installationwiki.org/Development_Environment_for_Skinning_DotNetNuke

Comment: Thanks i will try to install it and will get back to you

Answer (score 1):

An alternative: Charles Nurse recently published a walk through for using the new [WebMatrix product from Microsoft to install DotNetNuke](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Community/Blogs/tabid/825/EntryId/2689/WebMatrix-and-DNN-1-Using-WebMatrix-to-Setup-Your-DotNetNuke-Site.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

To know more about how to install DNN please flow the below link
https://mydnn.blogspot.com/2017/09/how-to-install-dotnetnuke.html
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-install-dotnetnuke